# Setting text color of child window

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to change text/background color for the static control. I can do this just fine the following way:

```
   // This is the 'main' window
   BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
   {
       hInst = hInstance;
       HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW &~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 1035, 764, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
       ...
   }

   LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
   {
     case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
        {
            MessageBox( NULL, "CTLCOLORSTATIC called", "", MB_OK );
            HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)wParam;
            SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(200, 200, 20));
            SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(10, 10, 10));

            return (INT_PTR)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(30, 30, 30));
        }
        default:
                return DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
   }
```

But  if I place the window inside another window,  the child control text/background color stays default:

```
    // This is the 'parent' window, which resides in the 'main' window
    HWND parent = CreateWindowEx
    (
        0,
        _TEXT("STATIC"),
        "",
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE  | BS_SOLID | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
        10, 10, 500, 500,
        hwnd,
        NULL,
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
        NULL
    );

    // This is the 'child' window which resides in the 'parent' window
    HWND child = CreateWindowEx
    (
        0,
        _TEXT("STATIC"),
        "SubItem",
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_SOLID,
        10, 10, 100, 100,
        parent,
        NULL,
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(parent, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
        NULL
    );
```

To conclude, I have 3 windows:

```
    HWND hwnd;   // the 'main' application window (color changes fine)
    HWND parent; // the 'parent/container' window which is inside the 'main' window (color changes fine)
    HWND child;  // the 'child' window which is inside the 'parent' window (color DOES NOT change)
```

Even though if I put MessageBox inside the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, I see it triggering every time the children is drawn, yet the color is not being changed for the child, only for the parent.

As far as I understood I need to handle the message in the main window procedure, but I'm not entirelly clear how to do this. if I compare the (HWND)lParam to the childrens HWND, they're the same (within the default switch case), so I can get the reference in the 'default' section,  but I'm not sure how I should handle it from there..

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {
        if ((HWND)lParam == child )
            MessageBox( NULL, "Reference Match for CTLCOLORSTATIC", "", MB_OK ); // <-- THIS NEVER TRIGGERS
    }
        ....
    default:
        if ((HWND)lParam == child )
            MessageBox( NULL, "Reference Match for DEFAULT", "", MB_OK ); // <-- THIS DOES TRIGGER

            return DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
        }
        return 0;
}
```

The reason I'm placing one window inside another is so that  I can use WS_CLIPCHILDREN property in the parent (becase the child will move/scroll).

Comment: Show more of your code, don't just describe it. You are also leaking brushes. Do you have 3 levels of windows?

Comment: @Andres sorry about that, I updated my question with more code. Yes, that is correct - I have the 'default/main' window, in which I'm adding the 'parent', and the 'parent' would contain a child window. The 'child' color (The third level window) I cannot update, but 'parent' color updates just fine as well as the 'main' window.

Comment: [WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/wm-ctlcolorstatic): *"A static control, or an edit control that is read-only or disabled, sends the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message **to its parent window** when the control is about to be drawn."*

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the reply. Sorry, but I'm not clear how to handle this. Does that mean I need to change its state to 'non-read-only' or do I need to handle this another way? How come level 1 and level 2 windows are not 'read only' but the 3rd level is? Thanks!

Comment: I put the **relevant** part in bold.

Comment: What @IInspectable is saying is that the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message is sent to the static window's parent. In your case, the static window's parent is the window you called `parent`. That's the one that needs to process the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message.

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks for the clarification! Does that mean I cannot catch this in WinProc method and have to create a 'subclass' for the 'parent' window which would also have this WinProc method, in order to catch this? Thanks!

Comment: See [Window Features: Child Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#child-windows). In fact, you should probably read the entire article. It contains lots of fundamental information, that's not repeated in the API documentation. Those are the ground rules you are expected to know when using the windowing API.

Answer (score 0):

`WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` is sent by a static control to its **parent window**, not the top level window.

```
hwndMain: WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC for hwnd1
|    
\--hwnd1: WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC for hwnd2 (You might have to subclass hwnd1)
   |
   \--hwnd2
```

You are also leaking brushes, store the brush from `CreateSolidBrush` somewhere when you create the window and delete it when the window is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptra) document, I know a function, `SetWindowsLongPtr`, whose parameter `GWLP_WNDPROC` can set a new address for the window procedure.

This function can change the text color and background color of the child window, that is to say, it can trigger `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`.

But after testing, I found that it is invalid to the secondary window, that is to say, it can not change the text color of the parent window.

I also consulted a lot of information, and very few documents related to three-tier windows.

So, I think to solve this problem and make all three windows change the color of the text, you may have to rewrite `WndProc` by yourself, but this is very complicated and involves a lot of things.

> Edit: If you just need to change the text color and background color
>   of the static control, you can customize a control so that you can
>   handle all its operations.

Hope to help you.